# Context in Drupal.attachBehaviors is object or string

Tags: 7, javascript

What do we really pass to Drupal.attachBehaviors in context, is it object or string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Drupal.attachBehaviors` has 2 arguments:

> - **context** - An element to attach behaviors to. If none is given, the document element is used.
> - **settings** - An object containing settings for the current context. If none given, the global Drupal.settings object is used.

So both arguments are objects, but can be `undefined` (or simply not provided) if required.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass strings, variable or array depending on your requirements.

Here I will show you really basic implementation:

You can call `drupal_add_js` function to include javascript in your module or theme:

```
// $your_variable contains the values you want to pass it to JS file.
drupal_add_js(array('exampleModule' => $your_variable), 'setting');
```

Below code goes to your javascript file:

```
    Drupal.behaviors.exampleModule = {
      attach: function (context, settings) {      
                // values passed from custom module can retrieved here as an object. check browser log for the values.          
               console.log(settings.exampleModule);
               // check length of the data object.
               console.log(Object.keys(settings.exampleModule.Data).length);
      }
    };
```

You can read more about it here: https://goo.gl/HgzZoI

Comment: The docs say both arguments should be objects - where are you seeing that an array is also acceptable?